# UIView's masked-off area still touchable?

Tags: ios

Say, I have a UIView with some controls on it. After I set its layer.mask which is smaller than view's bounds. Those invisible controls on the view can still be touched and respond. This is not expected by me.

Is there anything I missed, or any simple method to make masked-off controls untouchable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Masks and even transforms through CIFilters (iOS 5) only modify what you can see, not the area that you can touch. For that you need to override the [`hitTest:withEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest%3awithEvent%3a) and account for the image mask. You might have success by using [`[[[self layer] presentationLayer] hitTest:aPoint]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/hitTest%3a) or `[[[self layer] mask] hitTest:aPoint]` in your overridden `-[UIView hitTest:withEvent:]`