# How do I make a UIScrollView scrollable only when touches are inside a custom shape?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, mask, cashapelayer

I am working on creating an image collage app. And I am going to have multiple     `UIScrollView`'s. The scroll views will have boundaries with custom shapes and the user will be able to dynamically change the corners of the shapes where they intersect. The scroll views have `UIImageView`'s as subviews.

The scroll views are subviews of other UIView's. I applied a `CAShapeLayer` mask to each of these `UIView`'s. That way I can mask the scroll views with no problem.

But the problem is that, I can only scroll the contents of the last scroll view added. Also, I can pan and zoom beyond the boundaries of the masks. I should only able to pan or zoom when I am touching inside the boundaries of the polygons that I have as masks.

I tried;

```
scrollView.clipsToBounds = true
scrollView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

But the result is the same.

Unfortunately I'm not able to post screenshots but, here is the code that I use to create masks for the UIViews:

```
func createMask(v: UIView, viewsToMask: [UIView], anchorPoint: CGPoint)
{
    let frame = v.bounds
    var shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer]()
    var path = [CGMutablePathRef]()

    for i in 0...3 {
        path.append(CGPathCreateMutable())
        shapeLayer.append(CAShapeLayer())
    }

    //define frame constants
    let center = CGPointMake(frame.origin.x + frame.size.width / 2, frame.origin.y + frame.size.height / 2)
    let bottomLeft = CGPointMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y + frame.size.height)
    let bottomRight = CGPointMake(frame.origin.x + frame.size.width, frame.origin.y + frame.size.height)

    switch frameType {
    case 1:
        // First view for Frame Type 1
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path[0], nil, 0, 0)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path[0], nil, bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path[0], nil, anchorPoint.x, bottomLeft.y)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path[0], nil, anchorPoint.x, anchorPoint.y)
        CGPathCloseSubpath(path[0])

        // Second view for Frame Type 1
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path[1], nil, anchorPoint.x, anchorPoint.y)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path[1], nil, anchorPoint.x, bottomLeft.y)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path[1], nil, bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path[1], nil, bottomRight.x, anchorPoint.y)
        CGPathCloseSubpath(path[1])

        // Third view for Frame Type 1
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path[2], nil, 0, 0)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path[2], nil, anchorPoint.x, anchorPoint.y)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path[2], nil, bottomRight.x, anchorPoint.y)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path[2], nil, bottomRight.x, 0)
        CGPathCloseSubpath(path[2])

    default:
        break
    }

    for (key, view) in enumerate(viewsToMask) {
        shapeLayer[key].path = path[key]
        view.layer.mask = shapeLayer[key]
    }

}
```

So, how can I make the scroll views behave in such a way that they will only scroll or zoom content when touches happen inside their corresponding mask boundaries?

EDIT:

According to the answer to this question: [UIView's masked-off area still touchable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064524/uiviews-masked-off-area-still-touchable) the masks only modify what you can see, not the area that you can touch. So I subclassed the UIScrollView and tried to override the `hitTest:withEvent:` method like so,

```
protocol CoolScrollViewDelegate: class {
    var scrollViewPaths: [CGMutablePathRef] { get set }
}

class CoolScrollView: UIScrollView
{
    weak var coolDelegate: CoolScrollViewDelegate?

    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?
    {
        if CGPathContainsPoint(coolDelegate?.scrollViewPaths[tag], nil, point, true) {
            return self
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

But with this implementation, I can only check against the last scroll view and path boundaries change when I zoom in. For example if I zoom in on the image the `hitTest:withEvent:` method returns nil.

Comment: Can you just change the shape of the scroll views to match the custom shape?

Comment: You mean I apply the masks to the scroll views instead of their superviews? If I do that, it causes the contents of the scroll views to overplap when I scroll and it also adds blank spaces in the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with @Kendel in the comments - to start with it might be an easier approach to create a `UIScrollView` subclass that knows how to mask itself with a particular shape. Keeping the shape logic within a scroll view subclass will keep things tidy, and allow you to easily restrict touches to within the shape (I'll come to that in a minute).

It's a little hard to tell from your description exactly how your shaped views should behave, but as a brief example your `ShapedScrollView` might look like something like this:

```
import UIKit

class ShapedScrollView: UIScrollView {

    // MARK: Types

    enum Shape {
        case First  // Choose a better name!
    }

    // MARK: Properties

    private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    var shape: Shape = .First {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }

    // MARK: Initializers

    init(frame: CGRect, shape: Shape = .First) {
        self.shape = shape
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    // MARK: Layout

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateShape()
    }

    // MARK: Updating the Shape

    private func updateShape() {

        // Disable core animation actions to prevent changes to the shape layer animating implicitly
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

        if bounds.size != shapeLayer.bounds.size {
            // Bounds size has changed, completely update the shape
            shapeLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: contentOffset, size: bounds.size)
            shapeLayer.path = pathForShape(shape).CGPath
            layer.mask = shapeLayer

        } else {
            // Bounds size has NOT changed, just update origin of shape path to
            // match content offset - makes it appear stationary as we scroll
            var shapeFrame = shapeLayer.frame
            shapeFrame.origin = contentOffset
            shapeLayer.frame = shapeFrame
        }

        CATransaction.commit()
    }

    private func pathForShape(shape: Shape) -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        switch shape {
        case .First:
            // Build the shape path, whatever that might be...
            // path.moveToPoint(...)
            // ...
        }

        return path
    }
}
```

So making the touches only work inside the specified shape is the easy part. We already have a reference to a shape layer that describes the shape we want to restrict touches to. `UIView` provides a helpful hit-testing method that lets you specify whether or not a particular point should be considered to be "inside" that view: `pointInside(_:withEvent:)`. Simply add the following override to `ShapedScrollView`:

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    return CGPathContainsPoint(shapeLayer.path, nil, layer.convertPoint(point, toLayer: shapeLayer), false)
}
```

This just says: "If `point` (converted to the shape layer's coordinate system) is inside the shape's `path`, consider it to be inside the view; otherwise consider it outside the view."

---

If a scroll view that masks itself isn't appropriate, you can still adopt this technique by using a `ShapedScrollContainerView: UIView` with a `scrollView` property. Then, apply the shape mask to the container as above, and again use `pointInside(_:withEvent:)` to test whether it should respond to particular touch points.

Comment: Perfect! Subclassing the scroll views didn't achieve what I wanted, but I made the subclass `ShapedScrollContainerView: UIView` for the containers of the scrollviews. I can even receive touch events simultaneously from the scroll views. Thank you!